# React Router and Page re-drawing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a my Router set up like:

```
   <Router>
    <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/:pageId" component={Base} />
      <Route component={Home} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```

I did this so that the Navigation and Footer will not redraw every time I click a link. This works great. Now I want a new section  to NOT have the Navigation and Footer. If I move those two components into the Home and into the Base then every time I click make a selection in the Navigation everything re-draws. I don't know why that slight flicker bothers me, I guess because I have seen it work without the flicker.

I tried this with no luck:

```
<Router>
 {path !=== "/admin" && <Navigation />}
 <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/:pageId" component={Base} />
  <Route component={Home} />
 </Switch>
 {path !=== "/admin" && <Footer />}
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I posted this question. It was a long day. The conditional works using window.location.pathname. Easy fix, sorry for the interuption